# Problems with lexer parser implementation with loop statements in Kotlin (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Tags: kotlin, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to implement a simple lexer in Kotlin. I wrote the following code to get an integer as a token.

```
private var Code = "1+2*20-11%12*2"
private var CharIndex = 0
fun main(args:Array<String>)
{
    println("Input Code : ${Code}\n")
    lex().forEach{
        println("${it.TokenType} ${it.TokenText}")
    }
}
//Call ScanToken Method
fun lex():Array<Token>
{
    for(i in 0..Code.length - 1)
        ScanToken()
    Tokens.add(RilioToken("", RilioTokenType.EOF))
    return Tokens.toTypedArray()
}
private fun ScanToken()
{
    var ch = Code[CharIndex].toString()
    if(isNumeric(ch)){ //When it's a Integer
        var TempIntString = ch
        CharIndex++
        while(isNumeric(Code[CharIndex].toString())) //Keep receiving until receive non-numeric char.
        {
            TempIntString = TempIntString + Code[CharIndex].toString()
            CharIndex++
        }
        Tokens.add(Token(TempIntString, TokenType.Int)) //Return collected numbers
        println(TempIntString) //TEST Code
    }
    //other string
    else{Tokens.add(RilioToken(ch, TokenType.None))}
    CharIndex++
}
```

I thought the code would run as follows:

```
Input Code : 1+2*20-11%12*2
1
2
20
11
12
2

Int 1
Int 2
Int 20
Int 11
Int 12
Int 2
```

However, I got the following error in the code.

```
Input Code : 1+2*20-11%12*2
1
2
20
11
12

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:702)
    at com.ril.Riliolang.RilioLexer.ScanToken(RilioLexer.kt:77)
    at com.ril.Riliolang.RilioLexer.lex(RilioLexer.kt:16)
    at com.ril.Riliolang.TestKt.main(test.kt:8)
```

How can I prevent the CharIndex variable from exceeding the Index in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the end has been reached before incrementing.

```
if (CharIndex < Code.length) {
    CharIndex++
}
```